# Checking if three question marks appear between two integers that add upto 10

Tags: python

New to regular expressions. The regular expression I have below gets three question marks and more that appear consecutively but what if I wanted to get if there are three question marks appearing between two numbers that add upto 10 regardless if they appear consecutively or not.

```
import re


def has_three_question_marks(word):
    regex_pattern = re.compile(r"(\d\D+)(?=(\d))")
    question_marks = re.compile(r"\d(\D+)?\?{3,}(\D+)?")
    matches = re.findall(regex_pattern, word)
    if matches:
        for match in matches:
            question_mark_matches = re.findall(question_marks, str(match))
            if question_mark_matches:
                if int(match[0][0]) + int(match[1]) == 10:
                    return True
                continue
    return False
has_three_question_marks("arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5") #This returns True
has_three_question_marks("acc?7??sss?3rr1??????5") #This returns False, I need it to return True
```

Comment: As @PatrickArtner has asked kindly please, provide some examples of what data your trying to parse through the regex, and what sort of outputs you are expecting from the data, also possibly some incorrect data to help better assist you.

Comment: @PatrickArtner hope this is better

Comment: "***three question marks appearing between two numbers***" -  Exactly 3 or `>= 3` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito sorry greater or equal

Answer (score 0):

Better approach (ealier one after it):

```
import re
def splitting(text):
    n = re.split("\d","a"+text+"a") # make sure it does not start/end with ?
    q = [ques for ques in n if re.match("^\?+$",ques)]
    return sum(len(qq) for qq in q) > 2 


test = ["arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5","acc?7??sss?3rr1??????5", 
        "?5?5?5?", "1???1", "1?1?1?1","1??2?", "1??2?2","1??23?2"]

for t in test: 
    print(f"{t:<22} {splitting(t)}")
```

Output:

```
arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5  True
acc?7??sss?3rr1??????5 True
?5?5?5?                False
1???1                  True
1?1?1?1                True
1??2?                  False
1??2?2                 True
1??23?2                True
```

---

I do not quite know if regex is your tools to do that. Regex can not detect overlapping patterns:

```
'1?1?1?1' --> false
```

You can do it like this:

```
import re

test = ["arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5","acc?7??sss?3rr1??????5", 
        "?5?5?5?", "1???1", "1?1?1?1","1??2?", "1??2?2","1??23?2"]


def areThreeIn(text):
    patt = r"\d(\?+)\d"
    matches = re.findall(patt,text) 
    return sum(len(m) for m in matches) >= 3

for t in test:
    print(f"{t:<20} {areThreeIn(t)}")
```

Output:

```
arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5 True
acc?7??sss?3rr1??????5 True
?5?5?5?              False
1???1                True
1?1?1?1              False
1??2?                False
1??2?2               False # overlapping: would be True 
1??23?2              True
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this.  I'll preface this answer by saying that there are real limitations on what you can do with regular expressions alone, and for a sufficiently complex input you might need to write text parsing code that isn't just regex matching.  "Numbers that add up to 10" as a more general statement is something regexes can't do; a more classic problem that's theoretically impossible is checking if a string has a matching number of open and close parentheses, correctly nested.

If instead of "add up to 10" I say "if the start delimiter is 1 then the end delimiter is 9", and so on, then I should be able to build up a (complicated!) regex like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

# runs of things neither question mark nor digit
not_qmark_digit = r'[^?\d]*'
# contiguous blocks of non-digit with exactly three question mark
three_qmark = '(?:' + not_qmark_digit + r'\?){3}' + not_qmark_digit
# build a regexp matching 1...?.?.?...9 given the start digit
def delimited(start):
  end = 10-start
  return str(start) + three_qmark + str(end)
# make the 9 cases starting with each digit
cases = [delimited(n) for n in range(1, 10)]
# and join them as alternatives
pattern = '|'.join(cases)

x = re.compile(pattern)
print(x.findall("arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5"))
# ['6???4', '5???eee5']
print(x.findall("acc?7??sss?3rr1??????5"))
# ['7??sss?3']
```